# infinite loop showing random numbers js

Tags: javascript, loops, random, settimeout

My code is not working as I want to. It must show a random number but changes every some milliseconds that doesn't stop.

Here's the DOM:

```
<p>Random number:</p>
<p id="random_number"></p>
```

And my script:

```
var random_script = function() {
    while (true) {
        setTimeout(function(){
           var t = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
           document.getElementById("random_number").innerHTML = t;
        }, 1000);
    }
}();
```

But chrome keeps on crashing. Any help please?

Comment: Omit the `while` loop and use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) instead of `setTimeout()`.

Comment: You might do well to read this: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    setInterval(function(){
       var t = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
       document.getElementById("random_number").innerHTML = t;
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: one question, why does it run continuously even if it's not in a loop? I don't get it but it's working.

Comment: The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed. More info http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: ok. I need to research first before posting question. thanks nzn

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
(function(el, interval) {
    window.setInterval(function(){
        // you can use the math you were using, but I can't see the necessity
        el.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    }, interval);
})(document.getElementById('random_number'), 1000);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fXkh3/).

This approach is an immediately-invoked function expression, which passes the relevant parameters into the function which then sets up the function to be executed on defined intervals. This uses `window.setInterval` to repeat/re-invoked the passed function at repeated intervals, rather than executing it only once *after* an interval (as `setTimeout` does).

References:

- [Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions ('IIFE')](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).
- [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/5FE8p/ will help.

```
function myFunc ()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        var t = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
        console.info(t);
        document.getElementById("random_number").innerHTML = t;
        myFunc();
    }, 1000);
}
myFunc();
```

you should not call the settimeout multiple times at once. they are triggered asynchronously....